# Using with modifier with facebook API for users location

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a users location from `me/feed`

Like this

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
     $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    $feeds = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 
  array (
    'with' => 'location',
  )); 
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

When I print this it gives me the whole feed and not just the post with location like the API says it will... 
[Docs  Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/)

```
 print_r($facebook->api('/me/feed'));
```

And here is my code all together.

```
<?php        
require 'facebookAPI/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '0000000',
  'secret' => '000000000',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
     $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    $feeds = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 
  array (
    'with' => 'location',
  )); 
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
$params = array( 'next' => 'http://www.wuno.com/sandbox/actions/fbLogout.php' );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_about_me, user_checkins, friends_checkins, user_location, friends_location, read_stream')
  );
}
?>
```

Comment: do you `print_r` `$feeds` or `$facebook->api('/me/feed')` as `print_r($facebook->api('/me/feed'));` ;)?

Comment: Im printing like this  print_r($facebook->api('/me/feed'));

Comment: well in that case, you are **not** sending the parameter `?with=location` or in your case an array `$p = array('with' => 'location')`

Comment: so how would I print this? print_r($facebook->api('/me/feed', GET,

  array (
    'with' => 'location',
  ));

Comment: Yeah, try that out and quote GET like `'GET'`

Comment: the whole page does not load... if i do this it works but it shows all the feed not jus the locations.  print_r($facebook->api('/me/feed?with=location'));

Comment: when I do this <?php echo var_dump($feeds); ?> It gives me a bunch of raw data from my facebook wall. Hard to go through but I think its just a location feed. Because when I added a location to my facebook and refreshed it showed up at top. But when I added a new post with out location it did not. If var dump is working.. But when I echo $feeds I just get array array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54760/discussion-between-adam-azad-and-nichodiaz).

Comment: sorry man I was home. Let me know if you can help me.